# $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R $ be given by $f(x_1,x_2) = \sin(x_1)e^{3x_2+1} $. What is $f'(\pi,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

(i) Let $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R $ be given by $f(x_1,x_2) = \sin(x_1)e^{3x_2+1} $.
What is $f'(\pi,1)$?

My idea:

$f'(x_1,x_2) = \cos(x_1)e^{3x_2 +1} + 3\sin(x_1)e^{3x_2 +1} $

$f'(\pi,1) = \cos(\pi)e^4 + 3\sin(\pi)e^4 $

$ = -e^4 $

Is this correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by $\;f'\;$ for a function with more than one variable. Is it perhaps the gradient of the function, i.e. $\;\nabla f(\pi,1)\;\;?$

Answer (score 1):

1. $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\left(\sin(x_1)e^{1+3x_2}\right)=\cos(x_1)e^{1+3x_2}\to\cos(\pi)e^{1+3\cdot1}=-e^4$$
2. $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}\left(\sin(x_1)e^{1+3x_2}\right)=3\sin(x_1)e^{1+3x_2}\to3\sin(\pi)e^{1+3\cdot1}=0$$